How can I pre-authorize authopen in Rust?
I'm trying to create a os image flasher in Rust. To get permission to sd card, I am trying to use authopen as described in a previous answer.
Here is a small Rust example I created to reproduce the problem:
use std::{
    io::{Write, IoSliceMut},
    process::{Command, Stdio},
};      

use security_framework::authorization::{Authorization, AuthorizationItemSetBuilder, Flags};
use nix::sys::socket::{socketpair, SockFlag, SockType, AddressFamily, recvmsg, MsgFlags, UnixAddr, RecvMsg};
use nix::unistd::{close, pipe};
use nix::cmsg_space;


const DISK: &str = "/dev/rdisk2";

fn main() {
    open_auth(DISK);
}

fn open_auth(path: &str) {
    let rights = AuthorizationItemSetBuilder::new()
        .add_right(format!("sys.openfile.readwrite.{}", path))
        .unwrap()
        .build();

    let auth = Authorization::new(
        Some(rights),
        None,
        Flags::INTERACTION_ALLOWED | Flags::EXTEND_RIGHTS | Flags::PREAUTHORIZE,
    )
    .unwrap();

    let form = auth.make_external_form().unwrap();
    let form_bytes: Vec<u8> = form.bytes.into_iter().map(|x| x as u8).collect();

    let (srx, stx) = socketpair(
        AddressFamily::Unix,
        SockType::Stream,
        None,
        SockFlag::empty(),
    )
    .unwrap();
    let (prx, ptx) = pipe().unwrap();

    let mut cmd = Command::new("/usr/libexec/authopen")
        .args(["-stdoutpipe", "-extauth", "-o", "02", path])
        .stdin(Stdio::piped())
        .stdout(stx)
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();

    let mut stdin = cmd.stdin.take().unwrap();
    stdin.write_all(&form_bytes).unwrap();
    drop(stdin);

    let mut buf = [0u8; 4];
    let mut io_vec = [IoSliceMut::new(&mut buf)];
    let mut cmsg = cmsg_space!(RawFd);
    println!("Size: {}", cmsg.capacity());
    let msg: RecvMsg<'_, '_, UnixAddr> = recvmsg(
        srx.as_raw_fd(),
        &mut io_vec,
        Some(&mut cmsg),
        MsgFlags::empty(),
    )
    .unwrap();
    println!("RMSG: {:?}", msg);
    println!("Something: {:?}", msg.cmsgs().unwrap().collect::<Vec<_>>());

    println!("CMSG: {:?}", cmsg);
    println!("IOVEC: {:?}", io_vec);

    let output = cmd.wait().unwrap();
    println!("Raw output: {output:#?}");
}

Here is the output I get when I try to run it:
Finished dev profile [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.78s
     Running target/debug/temp
Size: 16
RMSG: RecvMsg { bytes: 2, cmsghdr: None, address: Some(UnixAddr { sun: sockaddr_un { sun_len: 0, sun_family: 0 } }), flags: MsgFlags(0x0), iobufs: PhantomData<&()>, mhdr: msghdr { msg_name: 0x7ff7b7f34166, msg_namelen: 0, msg_iov: 0x7ff7b7f34b68, msg_iovlen: 1, msg_control: 0x60000231c050, msg_controllen: 0, msg_flags: 0 } }
Something: []
CMSG: []
IOVEC: [[0, 16, 0, 0]]
Raw output: ExitStatus(
    unix_wait_status(
        256,
    ),
)

As you can see, the response I get does not seem to be correct. I would expect to get a ScmRights control message, but I am only getting 2 bytes of response.
I have not done any macos development before, so maybe I am just doing something stupid, so any help would be appreciated.

authopen: /dev/rdisk3: No such file or directory Seems like the root cause?

My bad. The path was incorrect in my short example. However, using the correct path does not change anything other than the error not showing up. Just tested.
I also tried /dev/disk2 but no luck.

Ok, so I was able to get everything working with help from someone who had a mac. Here is the function that opens the file:
fn open_auth(path: String) -> crate::error::Result<File> {
    let rights = AuthorizationItemSetBuilder::new()
        .add_right(format!("sys.openfile.readwrite.{}", &path))
        .unwrap()
        .build();

    let auth = Authorization::new(
        Some(rights),
        None,
        Flags::INTERACTION_ALLOWED | Flags::EXTEND_RIGHTS | Flags::PREAUTHORIZE,
    )
    .unwrap();

    let form = auth.make_external_form().unwrap();
    let (pipe0, pipe1) = UnixStream::pair().unwrap();

    let _ = Command::new("diskutil")
        .args(["unmountDisk", &path])
        .output()
        .unwrap();

    let mut cmd = Command::new("/usr/libexec/authopen")
        .args(["-stdoutpipe", "-extauth", "-o", "2", &path])
        .stdin(Stdio::piped())
        .stdout(OwnedFd::from(pipe1))
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();

    let mut stdin = cmd.stdin.take().unwrap();
    let form_bytes: Vec<u8> = form.bytes.into_iter().map(|x| x as u8).collect();
    stdin.write_all(&form_bytes).unwrap();
    drop(stdin);

    const IOV_BUF_SIZE: usize =
        unsafe { libc::CMSG_SPACE(std::mem::size_of::<std::ffi::c_int>() as u32) } as usize;
    let mut iov_buf = [0u8; IOV_BUF_SIZE];
    let mut iov = [IoSliceMut::new(&mut iov_buf)];

    let mut cmsg = cmsg_space!([RawFd; 1]);

    match nix::sys::socket::recvmsg::<()>(
        pipe0.as_raw_fd(),
        &mut iov,
        Some(&mut cmsg),
        MsgFlags::empty(),
    ) {
        Ok(result) => {
            tracing::info!("Result: {:#?}", result);

            for msg in result.cmsgs().unwrap() {
                if let ControlMessageOwned::ScmRights(scm_rights) = msg {
                    for fd in scm_rights {
                        tracing::debug!("receive file descriptor: {fd}");
                        return Ok(unsafe { tokio::fs::File::from_raw_fd(fd) });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Err(e) => {
            tracing::error!("Macos Error: {}", e);
        }
    }

    let status = cmd.wait().unwrap();
    tracing::debug!("Exit Status: {:?}", status);

    panic!("fd not found");
}

Note: The disk should be unmounted (as shown here using diskutil), before trying to open it.
For more complete picture, checkout the code in bb-imager-rs.

To pre-authorize authopen in Rust, you need to use the security_framework crate to create an authorization rights set for the specific disk path and initialize an Authorization object with appropriate flags, including PREAUTHORIZE. Convert this authorization to an external form, then spawn the authopen process with the correct arguments. Write the authorization form bytes to authopen's stdin, and then receive and process the response, looking for a file descriptor in the ScmRights control message. Ensure your application has Full Disk Access permissions and consider running it with elevated privileges. If issues persist, verify the correct disk path, check that the authopen binary exists at "/usr/libexec/authopen", and ensure your Rust code has the necessary permissions to execute authopen. Remember, to handle the errors appropriately throughout the process and use the latest version of the security_framework crate for compatibility with recent macOS versions. Hope this helps and good luck!

Can you point out what is wrong in my code? I think I am doing exactly what you described here.

Hi Ayush! Let's do a quick code review ... let mut buf = [0u8; 4];
let mut io_vec = [IoSliceMut::new(&mut buf)];
let mut cmsg = cmsg_space!(RawFd);
let msg = recvmsg(
srx.as_raw_fd(),
&mut io_vec,
some(&mut cmsg),
msgFlags::empty(),
).unwrap();
for cmsg in msg.cmsgs() {
if let ControlMessageOwned::ScmRights(fds) = cmsg {
println!("RX: {:?}", fds);
} else {
println!("fail: {:?}", cmsg);
}
}
